# How can I parse a Dialogflow v2 intent detection response in Python?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/api.html
I get such a response from Dialogflow, when parsing, I can't get the value. My conclusion is

tried to decode in .decode("utf-8") , but it decodes to the same with the double symbol \
I really work with Dialogflow, and before that I had no problems, as I used the first version of Dialogflow. Now I use dialogflow_v2 and this is a nightmare (((

Content:

```
fields {
    key: "lastName"
    value {
      string_value: "\320\241\320\260\320\263\320\260\320\271\320\264\320\260\321\207\320\275\321\213\320\271"
    }
  }
```

python:

```
lastName=response.query_result.parameters.fields["lastName"]
        print('lastName?+ {}'.format(lastName))
```

> out: lastName?+ string_value: \320\241\320\260\320\263\320\260\320\271\320\264\320\260\321\207\320\275\321\213\320\271"

Please how to recognize text in String_value:?
on the forum they say they apologize for the lack of documentation
https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/84

Comment: That isn't JSON at all; no compliant JSON parser in *any* language will parse it.

Comment: ...can you find out what syntax it actually *is* (CSS, maybe?), so we can try to find a parser written to the correct spec?

Comment: "From Dialogflow" is *some* clarification, but not much. "From the Dialogflow API call documented at [LINK]" would be far more useful. (Maybe our answer ends up being something like "to get that API to return JSON, change the Content-Type header"; who knows?)

Comment: @Charles Duffy this is the answer from dialogflow https://github.com/Romanchikus/Dialogflow.git

Comment: Heh. Yeah, that doesn't even **claim** to be JSON. `.js` != `.json`; JSON is a *subset* of JavaScript syntax. Though for it to be valid JavaScript either, the language must have changed quite a lot since I last knew it.

Comment: ...that said, that isn't "from Dialogflow" at all; it's just some random person's github project that they happened to name `Dialogflow`. If you find some real documentation from the actual Dialogflow project, that would be a much better place to start.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Excuse for troubling. I simply did not correctly name the file where I put the answer that comes from Dialogflow. I really work with Dialogflow, and before that I had no problems, as I used the first version of Dialogflow. Now I use dialogflow_v2 and this is a nightmare (((

Comment: Once again, **link to the Dialogflow documentation that describes the relevant syntax**. Only once we know what it's supposed to be can we speak to how to parse and generate it. And maybe rewrite the question to not be asking about JSON when your question has nothing to do with JSON whatsoever.

Comment: ...okay, now you're linking to the API *client*, but which / where is the documentation for the *specific call* that returned that content?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent

Comment: That's a gRPC call -- the response is a protobuf, not native JSON. The documentation shows what it looks like when it's *converted* to JSON, but there still had to be some code somewhere doing that conversion. Where/what is it?

Comment: Doesn't fit the documentation for a direct transliteration of the response to that call, either. You've got strings `Query text:` and `Detected intent:`, but there aren't keys with those strings in [DetectedIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/DetectIntentResponse).

Comment: Anyhow, in this case a [mcve] would need to include code to actually get a response in the given form back from Dialogflow.

Comment: Yes. That's an *object instance*, not a JSON document. So... how are you serializing it into text, to get the content you're trying to parse?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I think that the issue is not resolved, here is a discussion on the forum https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/84